# Why is my elevation shadow on the wrong side in react native?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

Why would my elevation shadow appear on the top and not the bottom?  When actually I'd rather it show up on the bottom.  How can I adjust where the elevation shadow appears?

```
const autoStyles = StyleSheet.create({
    suggestionsWrapper: {
        marginTop: 35,
        marginBottom: 5,
        position:'absolute',
        display:'flex',
        left:0,
        top:15,
        backgroundColor:'#fff',
        width:'100%',
        zIndex:10000,
        height:150,
        elevation:5
    },
    suggestion: {
        top:0,
        left:0,
        height: 30,
        padding: 5,
        borderBottomColor: '#ddd',
        borderBottomWidth: 1
    },
    suggestionText: {
        fontSize: 15
    },
    input: {
        fontSize: 15
    },
    wrapper: {
        flex: 1
    }
});
```

[image]

Comment: i feel lost when there are no free hand circles :/

Comment: ok I have added free hand circles to it.  The top circle shows the shadow where as the bottom circle shows the dropdown menu having no shadow.

Comment: I'm really sorry, the only time i try a joke it is taken seriously, i had a look at your rep before commenting to see if new user or not... goes through the door with shame -->[]